# Como fazer um um script no pug engine

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

Estou tentando fazer um script que contém uma função no pug engine, só que não consigo fazer com que ela seja chamada quando o usuário envia o form, alguém pode me ajudar?
Segue o código:

```
html
  head
    title= message
    script.
      funtion validator(){  
        alert("teste");
      }
  body
    h1= message
    form(method ="post", action="/cadastrar/marca")
      input(type="text", name="descricao", id="descricao")
      input(type="submit", onclick="return validator()")
```

Comment: Qual é o HTML gerado a partir deste arquivo?

Comment: <html><head><title>Cadastrar Marca</title></head><body><h1>Cadastrar Marca</h1><form method="post" action="/cadastrar/marca"><input type="text" name="descricao"/><input type="submit" value="save"/></form></body></html>

Comment: Primeiro, corrija o termo `funtion` que deveria ser `function`.

Comment: Testei seu código com https://html2jade.org/ e não consegui reproduzir o problema. Peço que edite a pergunta e adicione mais detalhes de como está gerando o HTML - e verifique se está gerando a partir do arquivo correto.

Answer (score 0):

Achei a solução, o problema era realmente a palavra "function" que estava errada, muito obrigado pela atenção, segue o código correto:

```
html
  head
    title= message
    script(src="validator.min.js")
    script.
      function teste(){
        alert("Teste")
      }
  body
    h1= message
    form(method ="post", action="/cadastrar/marca", onclick="return teste();")
      input(type="text", name="descricao")
      input(type="submit", value="save")
```

Comment: E por que no seu comentário sobre o HTML gerado não havia a tag script?